# How to save complicated object in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase

I have 2 classes. A class **User** which contains array of objects of class **Item**. I want to save object of **User** in Firebase. What do I need to do for it?

```
class User: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}

class Item{
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

var user = User(dictionary: [:])
user.name = "Tom"

var item = Item(name: "item1")
user.items.append(item)

let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).setValue(user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save them as firebase object.

```swift
class User: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var items: [Item]
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
    }
    var json: [String: Any] {
        return ["name": name, "items": items.map { $0.json }]
    }
}

class Item{
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    var json: [String: Any] { 
        return ["name": name]
    }
}

Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).setValue(user.json)
```